# How to fix navbar correctly?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Navigation Bar</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #navbar>ul>li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Navigation Bar</h1>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">google</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">google</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">github</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">github</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Career
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">google</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">github</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">bhagalpur</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

how am I supposed to make the list items side by side as they are appearing up and down and not side by side? I applied the inline-block property over them please someone also explain that why even this is happening?

Comment: You need to make your question clear as I cant figure out what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: no i want only non-nested list items to be inline, like in any normal website u can see.

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/nhwpdj3u/?

Comment: @MrLister please tell me why `home`, `contact us` ,`career`, `portfolio`   are not in same line

Comment: @vinay because they have different heights, and `vertical-align:baseline` which they have normally is aligning every _last_ line of text in each block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to align the top items on the same line, add

```css
vertical-align:top;
```

to the style. The problem was that your top-level list items are not all the same height, and the default vertical-align of `baseline` causes them to be aligned to the bottom!

```css
#navbar>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Navigation Bar</h1>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">google</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">google</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">github</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">github</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Career</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">google</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">linkidin sharma</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">github</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bhagalpur</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to make them at same height without using vertical-align property

Comment: Well, you can give them all the same height explicitly. Calculate what it should be based on the number of items in the largest menu. But it won't help, they will still have the same vertical alignment! Why don't you want to change that?

Comment: One solution would be to make the ul `display:table-row` and the li `display:table-cell`. I consider those things kludges though.

Comment: I figured it out by using `float:left` property? Am i right?.

Comment: yeah u'r right by using table-row and table-cell we can also do this,thanks for this extra info.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navbar>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

whether all the fit, depends on the width of the page

Answer (score 0):

Apply to the CSS:

```
ul li {
    float: right;
}
```

or style each li as using attribute style="float: right;" such as

```
<li style="float: right">
```

Comment: That will cause them to be displayed the wrong way around. (The first menu will be to the right and the last menu to the left.)

Comment: So it would: float: left; then. Also probably best to add margin-left: 10px inbetween

Comment: Maybe it's best if you test your answer for yourself before posting here.

Comment: I did but didn't notice that. Too used to using it for my own use with extra code surrounding.